# Почему Tornado игнорирует ВСЕ POST-запросы?

Tags: python, ubuntu, сервер, route, tornado

Сервер на Ubuntu Server 18.04, никаких специфический настроек ifconfig и тд нет (дефолтные).

```
GENERAL_ROUTE = ((r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": settings.DIR_WWW_FILES,
                                                        "default_filename": "index.html"}),
             (r"/vk/(.*?):(.*?)", handlers.VkCB),
             (r"/tg/(.*?)", handlers.Tg),
             (r"/donate/notification", handlers.Fk),)

HTTP_ROUTE = ((r"/(.*?)", handlers.HttpMain),
              *GENERAL_ROUTE)

HTTPS_ROUTE = (*GENERAL_ROUTE,)

class Main(ModulesBase):
    def __init__(self):
        http = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(
            tornado.web.Application(HTTP_ROUTE)
    )
        https = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(
            tornado.web.Application(HTTPS_ROUTE),
            ssl_options=SSL
    )

        http.add_sockets(tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(HTTP_PORT))
        https.add_sockets(tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(HTTPS_PORT))

        tornado.process.fork_processes(0)

        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

На все POST ошибка 405. Если убрать из GENERAL_ROUTE первую строку - всё равно на все POST ошибка 405. Во всех хендлерах есть метод post.

Comment: у вас что-то наверчено... воспроизведите ошибку в вопросе минимальным количеством кода, покажите ваши методы post

Comment: @EugeneDennis отредактировал, убрал несколько строк.

Comment: @EugeneDennis post-ы сами не отправляют 504, это точно :)

    class VkCB(TornadoBots):
        def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
            bot_name, key = args
            ...

Comment: если наследовать handler от простого `tornado.web.RequestHandler` что будет?